# JQuery and IE8 support

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

From the JQuery site, v.1.x supports IE6+, I'm using JQuery 1.7.2, but IE8 isn't playing along.

For instance, I have the following, very simple:

```
$("#close_dialog").click(function(){
  $("#form-dialog").fadeOut(300, function(){ $(this).remove();});
});
```

But in IE8 it doesn't trigger the click at all. If it was just a presentation problem, I could even overlook it, but this is a button that needs to be clicked, otherwise it impairs usability.

Any help on this? I'm not very proficient in JS, so I've been having fun with JQuery, but I have no idea how to make it work in IE8.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: v1.9.1 should support IE 7,8 & 9 so your code should work. Can you post a fiddle with the issue?

Comment: How do you know it's this piece of code? How do you know there isn't an error somewhere else in your JS that causes execution to stop so this piece of code never gets run?

Comment: Try using $(document).ready or place the script at the bottom of your page.

Comment: I will post a fiddle, sure, in a minute. :) The code is working properly in other browsers, no errors are being reported. Also, it's included in $(document).ready. I'm loading an external script, and I've set the type="text/javascript". Not sure why it doesn't work...

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/48xFC/ I wonder though... could it be because I'm testing with IE's developer tools/emulation? I've read posts about it not being 100% reliable. Anyway, if you could shed some light on this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't it defeat the purpose to post a fiddle when JSfiddle no longer supports IE8?

Comment: As I suspected, your code works absolutely fine. What the most likely culprit is that JS is running into an error elsewhere in your code where it stops, and it's never getting to this part. Seeing how you're using a newer browser in compat mode, open up the console, set to IE8 mode and take a look to see if you see any errors.

Comment: You're right. I'm loading enquire.js to help with some media queries and it's reporting an error on IE8. It's odd, because I had to refresh the page a few times for it to display the error. Well, one problem solved, now I have to solve another. :) Thank you very much.